# Inserting a column of pinyin for a column of Chinese characters using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm current using http://lxyu.github.io/pinyin/ which is working fine.

```
import pinyin

print pinyin.get(u'你好')
```

and i get 'nihao' which is correct.

With a CSV file of the following format:

```
陈升
"Mon Mon"
草蜢
李宇春
...
```

However, When I attempt to do this:

```
with open('ChineseNames.csv','rb') as fin, open('output.csv','wb') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(pinyin.get(line))
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "singerpinyin.py", line 12, in <module>
    writer.writerow(pinyin.get(line))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pinyin/pinyin.py", line 30, in get
    s = compat.u(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pinyin/compat.py", line 12, in u
    return unicode(s, "utf-8")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Trying:

```
writer.writerow(pinyin.get(u'line'))
```

Would give the wrong output:

```
l,i,n,e
l,i,n,e
l,i,n,e
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
it should be pinyin.get(line[0]).